# Store URL as String resource or in source code

Tags: android

I'm downloading data from a site using an `AsyncTask` which I start by calling `.execute()` and passing a URL `String` as a parameter, see below.

```
new GetRssFeedTask().execute("http://www.riksdagen.se/sv/Debatter--beslut/?rss=true&type=biksmall");
```

Should I store the URL in `strings.xml`? I have quite a few of them (around 20 different URL strings), so the above approach is less time consuming, but can it cause the app to crash in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes.

While Storing in strings.xml you also get language Support for free.
Imagine your Urls need to differ for different languages.

Example

> **values strings.xml** =>
>   http://www.riksdagen.se/sv/Debatter--beslut/?rss=true&type=biksmall&**lang=se**
>
> **values-de strings_de.xml** =>
>   http://www.riksdagen.se/sv/Debatter--beslut/?rss=true&type=biksmall&**lang=de**

PS: Your App will not Crash more or less with either Method.

Comment: In addition you get a much better overview once you need to change the urls if for example the server moved, etc.